# Using Array elements from one class into another class in same package

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to use array elements from one class into another. No error occurs but it doesn't print any values. Here is my code.

```
public class Cow implements Animal { 
    public   ArrayList<cage> getSchedule(ArrayList<cage> cages) {
        for(int a = 0; a < cages.size(); a++) {     
            Cage ct = (Cage)cages.get(a);
            A[a]=ct.getStart();
            B[a]=ct.getEnd();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

now I am trying to call arrays A[] and B[] in another class named `"KnapsackSolver"`. I copied the code from arraylist till return null and it shows no error. But when I try to print `A[]` and `B[]` in knapsackSolver class it doesn't print anything instead I say a message on console `"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"` .

Kindly help me out how can I use values of A and B arrays in `KnapsackSolver` class. To clarify the data in A and B is of double type and its declaration I have not shown here to save space and time. Looking forward to some suggestions.

Comment: This code probably doesn't compile, so how can you run it? I need to see the declaration of A and B to understand this.

Comment: I tried that also but it didn't worked and it doesn't give compile error but a line is displayed on console. Sorry if i mentioned something unclear as i am beginner to Java and programming.

Comment: You might want to include the relevant code in KnapsackSolver as well. You might just be referencing your array incorrectly.

Comment: Here is the declaration of A and B

double A []=new double[cages.size()];
   double B []=new double[cages.size()];

Comment: As it stands right now, there is no way Cow can see or use A nor B. So, the example is incomplete.

Comment: @MrBackend Sorry bro didn't get your point? what is missing here?
Shoudl i copy and paste whole code here?

Comment: @user3055784 At least the part of Knapsack you are using, and the part where A and B are defined. What is the scope (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) of A and B? (Edit: I suspect that you have two distinct pairs of A/B, and that you try to assign to one A/B and print another A/B)

Answer (score 0):

I think you you to use something like `return cages;` rather then `return null;` I think of that as following the [principle of least surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and it allows [Method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). Also, your `ArrayList<cage>` should almost certainly be `ArrayList<Cage>` - but I would prefer the more generic `List<Cage>` or even `Collection<Cage>`. Finally, an array of Cage(s) would be `Cage[] cages;` - ArrayList(s) are backed by arrays, but they're not the same thing as arrays. Have you implemented `toString()` in `Cage`? I would recommend that as well.

Comment: How can i implement toString() could you kindly write here the syntax. Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: @user3055784 Thanks for the clarification of how little knowledge of Java you have. I doubt I can help you until you have learnt the basics of the language.

Comment: @MrBackend Yes you are right i have just began to learn Java and encountered this problem. In short i have double values in A and B arrays in Cow class and want to use exactly same values of A and B in KnapsackSolver class but couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of sounding harsh, there's a lot of things in your code snippet that gives me the impression that you're only starting with programming.
There's nothing wrong with it, you just need to know what you're getting into :)

in java, it's common good practice to have your class names start with an uppercase (in your example, `Cow` instead of `cow`). 
Also, try to use the power of OO programming by using the interface when you can, in your example, use `List` instead of `ArrayList`.
somebody said that naming is one if the few hard things in programming. For example, we usually name our indexes `i`, `j`, `k`... We never start with `a`.
And then there's the return value of your function. It's typed to be a `List`, but it always returns `null`. you'd probably want to either change the return value to `void` (don't return anything) or actually return a list, even empty. 
I also have the impression that you're using `A` and `B` to return your schedules, which is in general not a good idea (besides the fact that you're naming a function get that doesn't gets you anything, you're also using instance attributes to transmit values between functions and creating 2 mutating correlated arrays rather than a single array of Schedules)

Now, to get back to your question, I would like to see the full declaration of `A` and `B`, but I suspect that either they're not being defined anywhere, or you're trying to use the return value of your method, which is always `null`. That, or the cages is a list of uninitialized objects (if `getStart` or `getEnd` returns a null `Double`, and `A` and `B` are `double`s, you'll get a NPE back)

Comment: Here is the declaration of both A and B. "double A []=new double[cages.size()]; double B []=new double[cages.size()];". Everything is working fine in Cow class. I tested that by adding print statement inside loop to verify data inside A and B it is of double type and gets printed. Now when i copy the above code with array declarations in KnapsackSolver class it doesn't print anything. That is my concern how to access and use same array values of A and B in KnapsackSolver class. I apologize in advance if said something unclear or illogical as i am new to java and want to learn it.